# z index not working when background is set?

Tags: html, css, z-index

i have an image advertise whose postion is fixed and z index is 40

```
#subHead{
   position: fixed;           
   height: 80px;    
   background: #c00;
   z-index: 40;
   margin-top: 140px;
}
```

i have a "post" container whose position is relative and z index is 34343443.It has blue image background 500 px in height

```
.post {
    background: url("http://.../Blue.png") top no-repeat;
    z-index:34343443;
    postion:relative;
}
```

Since z index of "post" container is higher,it should come above the advertise if they clash at one place.However the the image advertise whoose z index is 40 still comes above the blue background

[demo](http://ilovetrollstestbeta.blogspot.in/2012/12/top-14-funniest-pictures-of-day.html)

i am going literally mad after troubleshooting this for hours.plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `#subHead` is **in** the `.post` so it will always be displayed in front of it... In order to put it behind it you have to put it on the same level (e.g. in `.post-outer`).

Comment: i tried it.....still is comes above ..thanks a lot for you effort anyways :)

http://shrenuj.blogspot.in/2012/12/top-14-funniest-pictures-of-day.html

Comment: Yes, but the `#outer-wrapper` has no `z-index`, set the `#outer-wrapper` to a `z-index` higher than `#subhead` and you're done ;)

Comment: thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

By the way,you have a real neat website

Comment: neat and *awesome website